# How to use cursor to move video with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently trying to implement a function that will allow me to use the cursor to "grab" a video and move it around. I want to be able to only move the video when the cursor is held down and moved. I have defined the mouse events, captured the coordinates of my cursor but I am not sure how to write the function to crop the video.

```
x1, x2, y1, y2 = 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_down = False

def mouse_event_callback(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global x1, x2, y1, y2, mouse_down

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        x1, y1 = x, y
        mouse_down = True

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if mouse_down:
            x2, y2 = x, y
            mouse_grab_video(x1, x2, y1, y2)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        mouse_down = False

def mouse_grab_video(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    ...
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can crop the image directly based on the coordinate you get from your mouse event.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

drawing = False # true if mouse is pressed
ix,iy = -1,-1
refPt = []
img = ""
clone = ""
ROIRegion = []

# mouse callback function
def draw_rectangle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy,drawing,img,clone,refPt, ROIRegion
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        ix,iy = x,y
        refPt = [(x, y)]
        ROIRegion.append(refPt)
        #clone = img.copy()

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            img = clone.copy()
            cv2.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),3)
            a=x
            b=y
            if a != x | b != y:
                cv2.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,0,0),-1)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        refPt.append((x,y))
        img = clone.copy()
        cv2.rectangle(img, (ix,iy),(x,y), (0, 255, 0), 2)


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="Path to the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
img = cv2.imread(args["image"])
img = np.array(img)
clone = img.copy()

cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_rectangle)
while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == ord("r"):
        del ROIRegion[-1]
        del refPt[-1]
        img = clone.copy()

    elif k == 27:
        break

#Crop image to ROI
for region in range(len(ROIRegion)):
    cv2.rectangle(img, ROIRegion[region][0],ROIRegion[region][1], (0, 255, 0), 2)
    roi = clone[ROIRegion[region][0][1]:ROIRegion[region][1][1], ROIRegion[region][0][0]:ROIRegion[region][1][0]]
```

For zoom you may use EVENT_MOUSEWHEEL to increment scale and resize the image based on the scale. update imshow for latest image you scale. you can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870405/how-can-i-zoom-my-webcam-in-open-cv-python)

Comment: I know how to do for image, but what about moving a zoomed in video within the OpenCV window?

Comment: for zoom you can use mousewheel event to rescale the image. Refer to this link for the zoom part https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870405/how-can-i-zoom-my-webcam-in-open-cv-python

Comment: Hi, I've found out how to zoom in and out with mouse wheel events, but what I'm having trouble right now is using mouse click and hold to move the video frames around within the window while the video is playing. Is that possible?

Comment: Btw, I noticed you're the same person who replied on my previous post. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: I havent try this method yet to achieve what you looking for but you can try this RBUTTONDBLCLK  /  LBUTTONDBLCLK  then only use EVENT_MOUSEMOVE  to crop the image